# “slight” vs. “light” vs. “little”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

1. His skin color turns **slight** pinkish.
2. His skin color turns **slightly** pinkish.
3. His skin color turns **light** pinkish.
4. His skin color turns **a little** pinkish.
5. His skin color turns **little** pinkish.

Which one of these is correct?

Comment: #1 and #5 are completely unacceptable, and #3 isn't very likely (it would normally be *light **pink*** if anyone ever wanted to say something like that). #2 is idiomatically more common, but #4 is also "acceptable" (if a bit formal/dated/stilted). But they're all slightly odd, since *pinkish* pretty much means ***slightly pink*** (which is what most people would probably say).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: none of them.

As FumbleFingers pointed out in his comment, #1 and #5 are ungrammatical, and #3 extremely unidiomatic. While #2 and #4 are not entirely unacceptable, they are odd for two reasons.

First, the *-ish* suffix suggests "light" and "slightly" anyway, so the adverbs are redundant

Second, when speaking of changing complexion, one would ordinarily say "He turned slightly pink" rather than "His skin color turned slightly pink." This is true irrespective of the color: "During the storm, the inexperienced sailor turned green."

One would use "skin color" only to describe a relatively static medical condition: "The patient's skin color was yellow, suggesting a liver ailment." Even here, "color" is redundant. After all, yellow is a color.

Generally "skin color" is used only to characterize  race or caution against racism: "Don't judge people by their skin color." "Color" doesn't seem redundant here because I suppose "by their skin" could mean whether or not they have acne, callouses, or other dermal characteristics.

Comment: It seems like the OP could be answering a multiple choice question here, though. In which case, I think #2 would be the closest to being correct.